# Is there any way to disable automatic ('discretionary break') hyphenation, while allowing/forcing TeX to break some chosen words?

Tags: miktex, tex-core, hyphenation, polyglossia

I have a large document with narrower paragraph width than regular (approx 5 average words long), and I want to disable hyphenation short of having the opportunity to allow hyphenation of chosen words (usually where TeX produces horribly overflowing boxes as a result of not being allowed hyphenation and not having enough tolerance).

I know I can disable hyphenation with `\hyphenpenalty=10000` but then I cannot even get TeX to hyphenate anything, even explicitly (or do I?)

**Essentially, I want a white-list hyphenation strategy**. No hyphenation of anything, except words of my choosing, in places of my choosing, in hyphenation pattern of my choosing.

I have tried `\hyphenpenalty=9999` but that still allows TeX to occasionally hyphenate some words.

I am on MikTex, and use Xetex and polyglossia, but I am not sure if it matters all that much.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a possible way to do what you want:

```
\RequirePackage[english=nohyphenation]{hyphsubst}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\hyphenation{adip-is-cing}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, only `adipiscing` is hyphenated, because an exception for it has been defined.

In the text body you can still use `\-` for marking an allowed hyphenation point.

---

If the `nohyphenation` “language” is not defined, add some magic:

```
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{l@nohyphenation}{\chardef\l@nohyphenation=\@cclv}{}
\makeatother
\RequirePackage[english=nohyphenation]{hyphsubst}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\hyphenation{adip-is-cing}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

In my opinion, also MiKTeX should provide by default a language with no hyphenation patterns like TeX Live does; maybe it's possible to enable it from its control panel. The above code assigns `nohyphenation` to language 255, which is most likely still undefined.

Comment: THanks. However, MikTex tells me it does not know such pattern, 'nohyphenation'. Not sure how to proceed from there...

Comment: @amn I added a workaround; I guess, however, that enabling `nohyphenation` is possible from MiKTeX's control panel.

Comment: "Some magic" `\makeatletter...\RequirePackage...{hypsubst}` can be replaced by simple command `\language=255` given after `\begin{document}`. The `\hyphenation{words-exce-ption}` have to be set after `\language=255`.

Comment: @wipet Yes, that's a possibility, but maybe something else involving `babel` could be needed.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Are there any drawbacks to typeset in "language 255"? I mean does TeX not use the language as a hint for controlling some of its functions? I use Norwegian as a language, and I specify it for a reason. I hope the ligatures and other things related to localisation (displayed date and time, perhaps) do not break because of this?

Comment: @amn The value of `\language` is relevant only for hyphenation; `babel` uses the language name, so with `hyphsubst` the problem is bypassed.